# Apple's mobile operating system

Tags: ios4

am new in iphone technology i just wanted to know what is the memory that ios4 occupies in the iphone, i have read that i phone 4 has 512MB of RAM and in wiki i read that ios uses 500MB of ram so am bit confused like if it uses 500MB of ram then it leaves only 12MB free memory space for third party app, please help me out regarding this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you need to worry about.

If you needed to know, the information would be available.

Write your application and, if it uses too much memory, then optimise it.

You will receive memory warnings if you start to approach the memory limit, which you can respond to appropriately.

Comment: Thank u Jasarien for replying to this post

Answer (score 0):

It uses 500mb of *swap space*, which is space on the phone's actual storage, not RAM.

Comment: Amber first of all thank u for replying to my question, windows xp after installation takes some x amount of space in your system and uses some y amount of memory to run smoothly. i wanted to know the same for iphone